# save values of edit text using shared preference on text view in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, textview

I am designing an application in which I am taking use of shared preference.

I have taken 8 edit text, a text view and a button. I am using shared preference to store the values of these edit text and saving it on a single text view and sending these values to next screen on a click of a button.

When I am coming back to first screen, I am getting the values saved on the edit text.

But...When I try to edit any edit text, the text in the text view fully changes.

I want the values in the text view remains same unless it is edited and only the edited values are changed in the text view, rest remains same.

This is the code for first screen-

```
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String EventName = "eventname";
    public static final String Discount = "discount";
    public static final String ProductOffer = "productoffer";
    public static final String StartingTime = "startingtime";
    public static final String EndingTime = "endingtime";
    public static final String Address = "address";
    public static final String TimesRedeem = "timesredeem";
    public static final String ValidTill = "vslidtill";
    public static final String Output = "output";

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    eventName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.event_name);
    discount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.discount);
    productOffer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.product_offer);
    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);
    nextoffer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    startingTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.start_time);
    endingTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.end_time);
    timesRedeem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.no_of_time);
    etbirth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valid_till);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedpreferences.contains(EventName)) {
        eventName.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(EventName, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Discount)) {
        discount.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Discount, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(ProductOffer)) {
        productOffer.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(ProductOffer, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(StartingTime)) {
        startingTime.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(StartingTime, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(EndingTime)) {
        endingTime.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(EndingTime, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(ValidTill)) {
        etbirth.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(ValidTill, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(TimesRedeem)) {
        timesRedeem.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(TimesRedeem, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Address)) {
        address.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Address, ""));
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(Output)) {
        output.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Output, ""));
    } else {
        name = "Birthday";
        dis = "10";
        po = "Pizza";
        validtill = "DD-MM-YYYY";
        starttime = "HH:MM";
        endtime = "HH:MM";
        add = "XYZ";

        output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill + " from "
                + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at " + bus_name + ", "
                + add + ". T&C");
    }

    eventName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            dis = discount.getText().toString();
            po = productOffer.getText().toString();
            validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();
            starttime = startingTime.getText().toString();
            endtime = endingTime.getText().toString();
            timeredeem = timesRedeem.getText().toString();
            add = address.getText().toString();

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            name = eventName.getText().toString();

            if (name.length() == 0) {
                if(sharedpreferences.contains(Discount)){
                    sharedpreferences.getString(Discount, "");
                    output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                            + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                            + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                            + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
                }
                name = "Birthday";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            }  else {
                dis = "10";
                po = "Pizza";
                validtill = "DD-MM-YYYY";
                starttime = "HH:MM";
                endtime = "HH:MM";
                add = "XYZ";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            }
        }
    });

    discount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            po = productOffer.getText().toString();
            validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();
            starttime = startingTime.getText().toString();
            endtime = endingTime.getText().toString();
            timeredeem = timesRedeem.getText().toString();
            add = address.getText().toString();
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            dis = discount.getText().toString();
            name = eventName.getText().toString();

            if (dis.length() == 0) {
                dis = "10";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            } else {
                po = "Pizza";
                validtill = "DD-MM-YYYY";
                starttime = "HH:MM";
                endtime = "HH:MM";
                add = "XYZ";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            }
        }
    });

    productOffer.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();
            starttime = startingTime.getText().toString();
            endtime = endingTime.getText().toString();
            timeredeem = timesRedeem.getText().toString();
            add = address.getText().toString();
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            po = productOffer.getText().toString();
            name = eventName.getText().toString();
            dis = discount.getText().toString();

            if (po.length() == 0) {
                po = "Pizza";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            } else {
                validtill = "DD-MM-YYYY";
                starttime = "HH:MM";
                endtime = "HH:MM";
                add = "XYZ";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            }
        }
    });

    etbirth.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            starttime = startingTime.getText().toString();
            endtime = endingTime.getText().toString();
            timeredeem = timesRedeem.getText().toString();
            add = address.getText().toString();
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            name = eventName.getText().toString();
            dis = discount.getText().toString();
            po = productOffer.getText().toString();
            validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();

            if (validtill.length() == 0) {
                validtill = "DD-MM-YYYY";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            } else {
                starttime = "HH:MM";
                endtime = "HH:MM";
                add = "XYZ";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            }
        }
    });

    startingTime.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            endtime = endingTime.getText().toString();
            timeredeem = timesRedeem.getText().toString();
            add = address.getText().toString();
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            name = eventName.getText().toString();
            dis = discount.getText().toString();
            po = productOffer.getText().toString();
            validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();
            starttime = startingTime.getText().toString();

            if (starttime.length() == 0) {
                starttime = "HH:MM";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            } else {
                endtime = "HH:MM";
                add = "XYZ";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            }
        }
    });

    endingTime.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            timeredeem = timesRedeem.getText().toString();
            add = address.getText().toString();
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            name = eventName.getText().toString();
            dis = discount.getText().toString();
            po = productOffer.getText().toString();
            validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();
            starttime = startingTime.getText().toString();
            endtime = endingTime.getText().toString();

            if (endtime.length() == 0) {
                endtime = "HH:MM";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            } else {
                add = "XYZ";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            }
        }
    });

    timesRedeem.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            name = eventName.getText().toString();
            dis = discount.getText().toString();
            po = productOffer.getText().toString();
            validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();
            starttime = startingTime.getText().toString();
            endtime = endingTime.getText().toString();
            tr = timesRedeem.getText().toString();

            if (tr.length() == 0) {
                tr = "1";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");

            } else {
                add = "XYZ";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            add = address.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    address.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            name = eventName.getText().toString();
            dis = discount.getText().toString();
            po = productOffer.getText().toString();
            validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();
            starttime = startingTime.getText().toString();
            endtime = endingTime.getText().toString();
            tr = timesRedeem.getText().toString();
            add = address.getText().toString();
            if (add.length() == 0) {
                add = "XYZ";
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");

            } else {
                output.setText(name + " with friends & family. Get " + dis
                        + "% off on " + po + " till " + validtill
                        + " from " + starttime + " to " + endtime + " at "
                        + bus_name + ", " + add + ". T&C");
            }
        }
    });

    nextoffer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            name = eventName.getText().toString();
            dis = discount.getText().toString();
            po = productOffer.getText().toString();
            validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();
            starttime = startingTime.getText().toString();
            endtime = endingTime.getText().toString();
            timeredeem = timesRedeem.getText().toString();
            add = address.getText().toString();

            if (name.length() == 0) {
                eventName.setError("Enter Event Name");
            } else if (dis.length() == 0) {
                discount.setError("Enter Discount Value");
            } else if (dis.startsWith("0")) {
                discount.setError("Invalid Bill Amount");
            } else if (po.length() == 0) {
                productOffer.setError("Enter Product Offer");
            } else if (validtill.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please choose Date", 1).show();
            } else if (starttime.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please choose Starting Time", 1).show();
            } else if (endtime.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please choose Ending Time", 1).show();
            } else if (timeredeem.length() == 0) {
                timesRedeem
                        .setError("Enter number of times the offer can be redeemed");
            } else if (timeredeem.startsWith("0")) {
                timesRedeem.setError("Invalid Value");
            } else if (add.length() == 0) {
                address.setError("Enter Address");
            } else {

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

                try {

                    Date d1 = sdf.parse(starttime);
                    Date d2 = sdf.parse(endtime);

                    if ((d2.getTime()) > (d1.getTime())) {

                        offer_name = output.getText().toString();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Offers.this,
                                OfferCreate.class);
                        intent.putExtra("offername1", offer_name);
                        intent.putExtra("offer_discount", dis);
                        intent.putExtra("offer_valid_date", validtill);
                        intent.putExtra("offer_startingtime", starttime);
                        intent.putExtra("offer_endingtime", endtime);
                        intent.putExtra("offer_time_redeem", timeredeem);
                        intent.putExtra("offer_product", po);
                        intent.putExtra("offer_address", add);
                        intent.putExtra("offer_event_name", name);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else if ((d1.getTime()) >= (d2.getTime())) {
                        // System.out.println("deep less");
                        startingTime.setText("");
                        endingTime.setText("");
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String Eventname = eventName.getText().toString();
                String Discoun = discount.getText().toString();
                String Productoffer = productOffer.getText().toString();
                String Startingtime = startingTime.getText().toString();
                String Endingtime = endingTime.getText().toString();
                String Validtill = etbirth.getText().toString();
                String Timesredeem = timesRedeem.getText().toString();
                String Addresss = address.getText().toString();
                String Output1 = output.getText().toString();

                Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(EventName, Eventname);
                editor.putString(Discount, Discoun);
                editor.putString(ProductOffer, Productoffer);
                editor.putString(StartingTime, Startingtime);
                editor.putString(EndingTime, Endingtime);
                editor.putString(ValidTill, Validtill);
                editor.putString(TimesRedeem, Timesredeem);
                editor.putString(Address, Addresss);
                editor.putString(Output, Output1);

                editor.commit();

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Let us see some code,...

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have added/implemented "onTextChangedListener". So when you type something in edittext so the value of textview gets changed.

Though it is not getting stored in sharedpreference till you click button. So best way to stpo changing textview text is remove "onTextChangedListener".

OR

Simply dont set value to textview inside "onTextChangedListener". This will surely solve your problem.

Comment: @RIT....So how should i set text on text view without using onTextChangedListener..

Comment: Yes of course & I think in your case that is the only way to do so.

Comment: I already told you that way in my answer. Don't use setText inside On/addTextChanglistener() interface.

Comment: so how should I set text on text view on changing of the text on edit text?

Comment: Right now you are doing it. I said don't do that. Read my answer carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58308/discussion-between-rit-and-ashutosh).